# Re-indexing a network (graph) edge list

Tags: indexing, graph, graph-algorithm, networkx, pseudocode

My problem here is not language related, so a pseudo code answer would be more than fine.

Let' s suppose we are provided with an edge list that represents a graph and this edge list is in the classical 2-D matrix form. Let's also suppose that in this edge list the nodes are not numerated in a continuous way: in the resulting adj matrix there will be several raws and column full of zeros.
An example of this situation is the following:

- node1  node2
- 20     21
- 17     105
- 105     108
- 105     110
- 45     105
- 20     21

We want the nodes labels to start from 1 and end to N=number of nodes. We also want to preserve the order relations among each node: a node that in the previous labeling had and index i

- node1  node2
- 2     3
- 1     5
- 5     6
- 5     7
- 4     5
- 2     3

As far as I can think this task can be achieve in two ways: manipulating the edge list directly or creating first the (sparse) adj matrix and then deleting directly the raws/columns that are all zero (of course this latter action must be done with carefulness since deleting directly full zero rows and columns will not bring to the wanted result: trivial example the trivial matrix [0 1 0 0] that would result after the deleting process in graph with just one self loop).

I hope that I have stated clearly the question.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just get all the labels, sort them and use this sorted list to map each label to an int

```
// Part 1 : Get all the labels and order them
S = Set<int>
for edge E in edge-list
    S.insert(E.begin) // This is just getting the node1 
    S.insert(E.end)   // and node2
L = List<int>
L.insert(S) // Just put everything that was in S in a list
sort(L)
// In your example, you would have L = [17,20,21,45,105,...]


// Part 2 : Create a renaming of the labels
M = map<int,int>
for(int i = 0; i<L.length(); ++i)
    M[L[i]] = i

// You have your renaming. Each label has now an integer mapped to it
// It has all the properties you asked
```

Note that my new labels are 0-indexed, if you want the same thing as the example you gave, just do `M[L[i]] = i+1`

Now every time you encounter a label, for example `45`, you can call `M[45]` to get the new label

Answer (score 2):

If you have the graph as a `networkx` object, you can reindex nodes of the graph to `integer` labels using the [networkx relabel nodes function](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers.html#networkx.relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers)

```
import networkx as nx
old_graph = nx.Graph()
reindexed_graph = nx.relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers(old_graph, first_label=0, ordering='default') #first_label is the starting integer label, in this case zero
```